# Problem about the cut point of the connected space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $X$ be a connected topological space. Let $p\in X$ be such that $X-\{p\}$ is disconnected with separation $X-\{p\}=A\cup B$. Prove that $A\cup \{p\}$ is connected.

To be honest I spent many hours on this problem with my friend and we came up with the following approach.

**Proof:**  Since $X-\{p\}=A\cup B$ it means that $A,B$ are open in $X-\{p\}$. It follows that $A=U\cap (X-\{p\})$ and $B=V\cap (X-\{p\})$, where $U,V$ are open in $X$. It's easy to check that if $p\notin U$ then $U=A$ and if $p\in U$ then $U=A\cup \{p\}$. The same reasoning one can apply for the set $V$.
It leads to the following 4 cases which we have to consider:

**i)** $A,B$ are open in $X$; **ii)** $A, B\cup \{p\}$ are open in $X$; **iii)** $A\cup \{p\}, B$ are open in $X$; **iv)** $A\cup \{p\}, B\cup \{p\}$ are open in $X$.

The cases ii) and iii) are not possible. Otherwise, if $A,B\cup \{p\}$ are open in $X$ then $X=A\cup (B\cup \{p\})$ which is absurd because $X$ is connected.

**iv)** Suppose that both $A\cup \{p\},B\cup \{p\}$ are open in $X$. Suppose that $A\cup \{p\}$ is disconnected then there is a function $f:A\cup \{p\}\to \{0,1\}$ which is continuous but not constant. Let $f(p)=\alpha\in \{0,1\}$ then define function $g:B\cup \{p\}\to \{0,1\}$ which is constantly equal to $\alpha$ and hence is continuous. Since $X=(A\cup \{p\})\cup (B\cup \{p\})$ then by pasting lemma we can form the new function $h:X\to \{0,1\}$ which is continuous but not constant because $f$ is not constant. It means that $X$ is disconnected which is contradiction. Hence $A\cup \{p\}$ is connected.

**i)** Let both $A,B$ are open in $X$ and since $X-B=A\cup \{p\}$ and $X-A=B\cup \{p\}$ it implies that $A\cup \{p\}$ and $B\cup \{p\}$ are both closed sets in $X$. Using exactly the same reasoning for these function which I've applied for the case iv) I'll get that $A\cup \{p\}$ should be connected.

What do you think about this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine. In fact you have essentially proved the following lemma:

Let $X$ be a space and $R, S \subset X$ be two sets which are  both open or closed such that $X = R \cup S$ and $R  \cap S$ is connected. Then $X$ is connected if and only if both $R,S$ are connected.

The "if" part is well-known (and is true without requiring $A,S$ be open or closed). For the "only if" part assume that one of the subspaces, say $R$, is not connected. Then you find a non-constant function $f : R  \to \{0,1\}$. Since $R  \cap S$ is connected, it is constant on $R  \cap S$, i.e. $f(x) = a$ for $x \in R  \cap S$. Define $F: X \to \{0,1\}$ by $F(x) = f(x)$ for $x  \in R$ and $F(x) = a$ for $x \notin R$. Then $F \mid_R = f$ is continuous and $F \mid_S$ is constant, hence continuous. Since $R,S$ are open or closed, $F$ is continuous but non-constant, a contradiction.